# Is there a user friendly XML editor out there? I can't find anything good, preferably open source

Tags: xml, editor

Something to take an XML schema and let you add/edit data but not change the XML structure, preferably installed on a server. basically a UI to edit xml documents as a web app. Someone has got to have done this already right?

Answer (score 6):

[Xopus](http://xopus.com) is a commercial XML editor designed specifically to be used by non-technical people. Xopus is browser based and can be installed on any webserver. Xopus keeps the XML document 100% valid at all times using XML Schema and has a WYSIWYG view using XSLT.

You could use the [DOM API](http://xopus.com/documentation/developer-guide/reference/xopus-api.html) to configure it so that only the text can be changed, not the structure.

Direct [link](http://xopus.com/files/demo/xopus/xopus.html#/files/demo/examples/Recipe/start.html) to a demo.

Answer (score 4):

[Liquid XML](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/) have a nice free version

update: (as of March 10 2010) it seems that the editor is no longer free

Comment: Liquid XML does not appear to be web based or offer a free version (nothing obvious on their website)

Comment: read for comprehension, he asked for web based and free

Answer (score 1):

IMHO [BXE - The Wysiwyg XML Editor](http://bitfluxeditor.org/home/) can do this - i.e. create/edit XML document in browser, based on existing XML Schema.
I am not sure, but you probably have to include it in your own page, it is just the editor component, not the full web application.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "user friendly", and what you want out of a text editor. I personally use emacs for editing xml, but I'm willing to put up with the learning curve of the editor for the sheer power it gives me - editing XML is now rather easy and painless for me, but it took me a bit to get it to that point.

[oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) looks like it might fit what you want, but it's not free.

[This page](http://ahds.ac.uk/creating/information-papers/xml-editors/) has a good comparison of xml editors and there features, seems like a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

[XML Copy Editor](http://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.net/) is free and GPL

Answer (score 0):

Check out microsoft for an [XML Notepad 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=72d6aa49-787d-4118-ba5f-4f30fe913628&displaylang=en). I'm not to fond of it, since it really treats xml as a tree as opposed to plain text, but that is what you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

I personally like Notepad++ with the XMLTools plugin.
It will unfortunately allow you to edit the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a web-app that allows you to write an instance document based on an uploaded schema (as yet.. mebbe I should write one? :) ).

[Altova XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/products/xmlspy/xml_editor.html) is pretty much the best of the editors I have used, but very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Give vim a try with a suitable plugin (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=301).

/Allan

Comment: vim is for power users, it's not something my mother would use to edit her xml.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with the [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/eclipse_plugin.html) plugin, that would be my recommendation, free open source and very widely used. Altova XML Spy is a great tool but expensive, they used to do a free non-commercial use edition but that doesn't appear on their website now so perhaps they have discontinued that.

Answer (score 0):

[XML Editor](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/) is free (whereas the various FO converters are not) and you can use it with [FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) (from the Apache project).  Emacs with the psgml module can do it along with vim but both probably more low-lovel).  Eclipse can do it too but iut is rather heavyweight.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an XML editor with code folding and a node explorer (something Visual Studio is missing) [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org) has both, and is free and open source

[image: Netbeans XML editor]